# Passing char[] parameters doesn't work at all

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, parameters

Okay, so I have a code for trimming the duplicate characters in a string,
based on [here](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/59171.html). Okay, I modified to become like this:

```
    void rem_dup(char str[]){
    int     char_check=0;
    int     i,j;
    char    ch;
    char    filterstr[256]; /* store the temporary strings */

    /* check from 1st character in the string */
    while(str[char_check]) {

            ch = str[char_check];

            i = j = char_check+1;

            filterstr[0] = str[0]; // added

    /* logic to remove the repeated character */
    while(str[i]) {
            if(str[i] != ch) {
                    filterstr[j] = str[i]; //modifid
                    j++;
            }
            i++;
    }

    filterstr[j]='\0'; //modified

    str = filterstr; //added

    char_check++;

    }

    printf("String after removing duplicates : %s\n",str); this
    }
```

And the I implement this by doing a simple script

```
    int main(){
        char Q[20];
        char E[26];

        fgets(Q,sizeof(Q),stdin);
        fgets(E,sizeof(E),stdin);

        rem_dup(Q);
        rem_dup(E);

        printf("\n%s\n%s\n",Q,E);
        return 0;
    }
```

I expect the output just like this

```
    0101010101
    ababababab
    String after removing duplicates : 01
    String after removing duplicates : ab
    01
    ab
```

However the output will become this

```
    0101010101
    ababababab
    String after removing duplicates : 01
    String after removing duplicates : ab
    0101010101
    ababababab
```

As you can see, the reality is the Q and E doesn't trimmed at all. If the array parameters is parameters-by-reference, and how can this kind of things happened to me?? Anyone has the answer to that?? I've searched many source and trying this only problem, but always failed. Thanks for answering or just giving opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
str = filterstr;
```

is not doing what you thing it is. That code simply changes the local copy of the pointer to the buffer. It does not change the buffer's contents.

You need to call

```
strcpy(str, filestr);
```

just before the function returns, i.e. where your `printf` is now.

Looking at your logic, I believe it will fail for more complex inputs. I'm not going to attempt to debug it for you because I am not 100% sure of what you want the code to do.

Comment: thanks. actually those are the sinppets for implementing the DFA Machine. I want to filter duplicate strings in the sets of DFA.

Answer (score 0):

The line `str = filterstr;` makes `str` (and therefore, `Q`) point to `filterstr`. When the function exists, `filterstr` gets destroyed and `Q` regains its original value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you pass in the pointer you are not getting a reference to the actual object but a copy of the pointer to the object or this case a buffer. So when you say

```
str = filterstr
```

it doesn't change the original pointer or the one in the main but the local copy. That's why you see the trimmed string inside the function and not outside.

Also since filterstr is also local variable, just changing the pointers will not work you need to use strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify the whole thing to a few lines, avoid temporary storage like this:

```
void
rmdups(char *str)
{
     char *sp;
     for(sp=str; *sp; sp++){
          char *lo, *hi;
          for(lo=sp, hi=sp+1; *lo; hi++)
               if(*hi!=*sp)
                   *++lo = *hi;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the simpler solution. I think I will use this. Would you mind if I publish this snippet sometimes?